# Перестал отображаться знак местной валюты (в моём случае индийских рупий, ₹), вместо него теперь виден знак рубля. В чём проблема?

Tags: php, текст

Пишу интернет магазин в обучающих целях и заметил выше описанную проблему. Сам знак пишу не кодом, а символом. Пробовал откат последних изменений, проблема не исчезает.

В итоговой html разметке в коде прописан всё тот же символ ₹. Кода у символа нет. Гарнитура Futura PT

```
Фрагмент:
                                <span>
                                    5000 ₹
                                </span>
```

Вывод:

[image]

Comment: Куда пишете, как пишете, каким символом, какой код у этого символа, каким шрифтом этот символ рисуется?

Comment: Может Индия на рубль переходит, вот значек и сменился? )

Comment: html-код используйте (`&#8377;` или `&#x20b9;`)